# How to align multiple divs vertically on the left? Both divs has different width

Tags: html, css

**My code**

```
  <div className="about__sec">
      <div className="aboutMe">
        <p>
           Hello, I’m Ajeeth. <br /> Looking for an internship in Front-end or
          web developer
        </p>
        <p>
          Currently working at VVDN Technologies as a component Engineer,
          helping to design the electrical board (PCB).
        </p>
        <p>
          I’m an PCB designer with over 2 years of experience in designing a
          printed circuit board. I'm an innovative and dedicated design
          professional dedicated to satisfying my customer’s design
          requirements. I enjoy the challenge of finding unique ways to fulfill
          my customer’s needs.
        </p>
        <p className="email" >
          Let’s talk me on <span>hello@ajeeth.me</span>{" "}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="about-my-past">
        <div className="about-my-past--left">
          <div className="about-my-past--content">
            <p>
              I am a mechanical engineer by profession, but I have always had a
              passion for coding. As such, I have decided to switch my career
              path and become a frontend developer.
            </p>
            <p>
              I have been teaching myself coding and have gained a good amount
              of knowledge in HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Bootstrap and React.
            </p>
          </div>
          <img src={Profile_1} alt="profile" />
        </div>
        <div className="about-my-past--right">
          <img src={Profile} alt="" />
          <div className="about-my-past--content">
            <p>
              I am an avid learner, always looking for ways to expand my
              knowledge and develop new skills.
            </p>
            <p>
              I stay up to date with the latest technologies and trends in
              software development, allowing me to stay ahead of the curve.{" "}
            </p>
            <p>
              I am highly organized, have strong problem solving skills, and am
              able to work independently or as part of a team.{" "}
            </p>
            <p>
              I am excited to take on new challenges and to develop projects
              that I can be proud of. With my passion and drive, I am confident
              that I can make a positive impact in the software industry.
            </p>
            <p>
              In conclusion, I am a highly motivated and creative individual who
              is constantly looking for ways to improve my skills and challenge
              myself. I have the right
            </p>
            <p className="email" >
              Let’s talk me on <span>hello@ajeeth.me</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .about__sec {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #f6f7f2;
  font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 auto;
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
}

.aboutMe {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 685px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 84px 0 52px 0;
}

.aboutMe > p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.aboutMe p:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: #4f5358;
  font-size: 0.72em;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
}

.email {
  font-size: 0.64em;
}

span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (max-width: 685px) {
  .aboutMe {
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.about-my-past {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 26px;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 860px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.about-my-past--left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-width: 417px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.about-my-past--content p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.about-my-past--left img {
  max-width: 417px;
  max-height: 758px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.about-my-past--right img {
  max-width: 417px;
  max-height: 585px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

The above showed an example code for my project. I need a solution for that, I have to place the class "aboutMe" horizontally centered on the screen & class "about-my-past" which is the place start where the class "aboutMe" strat **which I have attached an image of**.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gir6.png)

Please here to solve

Comment: what is expected output like ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following CSS properties to .App element

```css
flex-direction: column;
align-items: start;
```

Answer (score 0):

both grid and flex layouts have their respective cases, imo this sounds like one for grid with auto margins

but with the limited information, i cannot say for sure. flex as in [Shakya Peiris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75120300/13982210) or grid. whichever works for you

```css
.App {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0px auto; 
    /* ^ centers on the horizontal axis*/
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}
.one, .two {
  width: max-content;
  /*note: using auto margins 
          will center them within 
          the grid. do not use margin: 0 auto;
          */

}
```